# accordion-toggle check open close - Angular active/inactive

Tags: angular, typescript, accordion

Here is my HTML page which has dynamic toggle shown below.

```
<tr align="center" *ngFor="let section of sectionList ; let RowIndex = index;">
   <td colspan="6">
      <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="table table-bordered bg-white">
         <tr>
            <td><button (click)="checkUncheck(RowIndex)" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#SectionDemo'+ RowIndex"
               class="accordion-toggle" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span
                  class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span>+</button>
            </td>
            <td>{{section.sectionName}} {{RowIndex}}</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="6">
               <div class="hiddenRow">
                  <div class="accordian-body collapse" [attr.id]="'SectionDemo' + RowIndex">
                     yeah man test {{RowIndex}}
                  </div>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Now the thing is I want to get the open/close in **typescript** true false, so far what I've done is.

```
checkUncheck(event){
    console.log(event);
    setInterval(j => {
      const domElement = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector(`#SectionDemo` + event);
      console.log(domElement);
      clearInterval();
    }, 1500);
}
```

Now the result which I get is this.

```
<div _ngcontent-khl-c237="" class="accordian-body collapse show" id="SectionDemo0" style=""> yeah man test 0 </div>
```

from `console.log(domElement);`
Now here I want to get `class="accordian-body collapse show"` without **setInterval** so I can at least from `accordian-body collapse show` make true/false from open/close.

Comment: Why are you checking the DOM if some class is on there? Isn't that under your control? To make an accordion all you need to do is either use the `*ngIf` structural directive or bind to `[ngClass]` or `[ngStyle]` and return styling depending on a condition or boolean. The last one is useful if you also want some animation.

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 an example would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Directive [ngClass]

Script:

```js
isCollapsed = true

toggleCollapsed() {
  this.isCollapsed = !this.isCollapsed
}

getAccordionStyle(event) {
  return isColapsed ? 'collapsed' : 'not-collapsed'
}
```

Template:

```html
<div (click)="toggleCollapsed()">Some accordion item... </div>
<div [ngClass]="getAccordionStyle()"> Your collapsed content here... </div>
```

CSS:

```css
.collapsed {
  display: none;
  /* Your collapsed styling */
}

.not-collapsed {
  /* Your styling when not collapsed */
}
```

### Structural Direcrtive *ngIf

Script:

```js
isExpanded = false

toggleCollapsed() {
  this.isExpanded = !isExpanded
}
```

Template:

```html
<div (click)="toggleCollapsed()">Some accordion item... </div>
<div *ngIf="isExpanded"> Your collapsed content here... </div>
```

Here's a basic example on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mkwqwt).

Comment: Well its nice answer but still my accordion are in a `ngFor` loop and that makes it a dynamic accordion your answer do help but only for single accordion, how can I make it dynamic with `*ngIf="isExpanded"` if I want to as I try to open another it pushes the previous accordion as well.

Comment: You can use this in an *ngFor too... Just wrap what you see above with `<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items"> Accordion item from answer above here... <ng-container>` and store the booleans in an array of booleans instead of just the one....

Comment: its wrapped as `<tr align="center" *ngFor="let section of sectionList ; let RowIndex = index;"></tr>` which gives me `RowIndex` that appends the `[attr.data-target]="'#SectionDemo'+ RowIndex"` you can see it has the complete code in the question

Comment: Yeah you can wrap it in anything, the idea stays the same. If you really want I can make an example later.

Comment: Sure that'll help for the dynamic I'll wait for your answer sir thank you a lot.

Comment: @NamanKumar Check the Stackblitz at the bottom of the answer. Cheers